# Talend - How to disable checking of extra features?

Tags: talend

Is there a way of disabling the option "Checking for extra features"? This happens on Talend Open Studio Start as show in image below and it makes the studio hang/stuck. I am using Talend Open Studio for Data Integration v7.2.1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [this JIRA item](https://jira.talendforge.org/browse/TUP-2378) on their Talend Unified Platform, you can disable this check by adjusting configuration.

1. Navigate to configuration folder.
2. Click `.settings` folder.
3. Open up files `org.talend.updates.runtime` and `org.talend.updates`
4. Change `do.not.show.wizard=false` to `do.not.show.wizard=true` in both files.

Comment: I cannot find "org.talend.udpates.runtime" and "org.talend.updates" in configuration/.settings folder. I am using open studio 7.2.1